# Cannot get a simple console log to work in Titanium Studio

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I searched the documents and am trying to just log a variable in the console. I am using:

```
aptana.log("My variable is " + myVariable);
```

When I run the app, I am getting an error:

```
message = "Can't find variable: aptana";
```

It cant be this difficult for something so simple, can it?

Answer (score 2):

Can't find anything about aptana.log() in the docs. Try using Titanium.API.Log() instead.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/api/Titanium.API-method-log

Comment: Note that Ti.API.info/warn/error are probably what you want. Those all take a single argument and send it to the console. Ti.API.log takes two arguments, the first being the log level, and the second being the actual message.

Answer (score 0):

have you just tried

```
console.log("My variable is " + myVariable);
```

or

```
console.debug("My variable is" + aptana.myVariable);
```

Comment: `console.log` and `console.debug` will work in Titanium Mobile Web in CERTAIN BROWSERS only. Can't remember if they work on Android or iOS (in Titanium Mobile), but I know the docs don't specify that they are there. I know that Ti.API.info/warn/error/log work.

Answer (score 0):

iOS10 Currently does not work with logging (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23786), it will be fixed shortly.  So if you are using iOS10 you'll have to wait to see the log messages.